# Facebook contact sync no longer working: "Sync is currently experiencing problems. It will be back shortly"

Tags: sync, facebook

As of a couple of weeks ago my Galaxy S3 (running Android 4.1.1) no longer syncs contacts from Facebook. I have the Facebook app installed and calendar and the gallery are syncing fine but the contacts fail. I get the following message:

> Sync is currently experiencing problems. It will be back shortly.

Just to be clear, it did used to sync the contacts fine, but then the above started happening. I have updated the Facebook app a few times but I cannot remember if it started happening immediately after one of these updates. Anyone know what's going on or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Samsung phones have a proprietary app to synch with social networks: **SNS Provider**. So to solve it you probably have to search/wait for an update to it in Galaxy Apps.

You can also check your preferences in Facebook app, it has its way to synch contacts and gallery. There should be an option related to contacts synch, check that it's activated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing and re-adding the Facebook account in your "Accounts and Sync" settings? Sometimes something in the sync process can get corrupted (left half-finished, etc) and that prevents future sync attempts from working properly. If you clear the account info off the phone and then re-sync it (Wi-Fi recommended) you should get a clean copy.

If that doesn't work, something's borked with your Facebook app; try completely uninstalling and reinstalling the app (or at least remove all updates, if your phone/provider considers Facebook a "system app"). If you'd said that none of the Facebook sections were syncing properly, I'd say you were on a LAN that was blocking access to the domain, but that's apparently not the case here.

Comment: Tried removing the account and then re-adding it but no luck. I'm pretty sure I already tried deleting and reinstalling the whole app already with no success. Guess I might have to try again.

Answer (score 0):

I have several photo albums from FB on my Galaxy S3 and noticed it was missing a few. Going into the phone's *gallery -> settings -> accounts (FB)->remove account ->* re-log back in and it's fixed both the calendar and the gallery sync. Note* make sure in *gallery -> content to display -> content in Facebook* is checked.

Answer (score -1):

Try installing Facebook APK manually following this steps:

- On your phone go to Settings > Security and check the "Allow unknown sources" check box
- Download the latest (to the date of this answer) Facebook apk from [here](http://dl.updatedapps.com/com.facebook.katana-v39.0.0.0.88-12733034-Android-5.0.apk)
- After the download is finished, click on the apk in the list of downloaded items or go to `/sdcard/downloads` with a file manager app like [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) and open the apk file.
- The installation screen should appear showing the permissions asked by the app. Click on "Install" at the bottom of the screen.
- Wait for the installation to finish then click on "Open" to open the Facebook app.

Now you have the latest Facebook app - let's fix the Play Store issue:

- Go to Settings > Applications > All. Search for the Play Store app and click on it.
- The info about the Play Store will appear. Wait until the "Delete data" button is click-able then click on it and confirm.
  0 Now go back to your same screen and launch the Play Store and wait for it to load your account, then go to the "My Applications" tab and you should see the Facebook app there (if it's not try rebooting your phone).

You are all set. You now have the latest Facebook version and it will be updated normally through the Play Store.